# How to get url of view using django.core.urlresolvers.reverse

Tags: django, unit-testing, reverse

I have URL pattern in urls.py in a Django project like this.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^web/', include('project.web.weburls')),
]
```

and in my weburls.py file I have this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', webview.home)
]
```

and in the webview file, I have this:

```
def home(request):
    pass
```

in my test file, I have written test case like bellow,

```
url = reverse("project.web.weburls.webview.home")
```

but it gave me an error.
NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'project.web.weburls.webview.home' not found.

Why do I get this? what mistake do I have in using this method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to @gonczor,
I need to import webview at top of the file and call reverse(home) instead of using URL namespaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reverse your Django project's URL namespaces, not python code. In order to do this you'll have to call `reverse('home')` or `reverse(home)`. Compare with [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

> reverse(viewname, urlconf=None, args=None, kwargs=None, current_app=None)
>   viewname can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object. For example, given the following url:

Comment: Thank you, yes I had to import webview at top of the file and call reverse(home) instead of using URL namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

first you need to give a name to your url route.

```
path('archive/', views.archive, name='news-archive')
```

from django.urls import reverse

then you can use reverse() function for getting url reverse.
see django documentation from the link below:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/urlresolvers/

and take a look at django testing using reverse in unittesting.

https://django-testing-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/views.html#getting-into-context